# Multiple linear regression in python without fitting the origin?

Tags: python, numpy, regression

I found this chunk of code on http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Multiple_regression#Python, which does a multiple linear regression in python. Print b in the following code gives you the coefficients of x1, ..., xN. However, this code is fitting the line through the origin (i.e. the resulting model does not include a constant).

All I'd like to do is the exact same thing except I do not want to fit the line through the origin, I need the constant in my resulting model.

Any idea if it's a small modification to do this? I've searched and found numerous documents on multiple regressions in python, except they are lengthy and overly complicated for what I need. This code works perfect, except I just need a model that fits through the intercept not the origin.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import random

n=100
k=10
y = np.mat(random((1,n)))
X = np.mat(random((k,n)))

b = y * X.T * np.linalg.inv(X*X.T)
print(b)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you only need to add a row to X that is all 1.

Comment: Take your matrix of observations (right hand side variables, where column 1 is for the first variable, column 2 for the second, etc.) and prepend a column of all ones, such as `numpy.ones(N)` where `N` is the number of observations in your regression. Then the coefficient on the all-ones column will be the intercept term.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a more stable approach would be to use a least squares algorithm anyway. This can also be done in numpy in a few lines. Read the [documentation about numpy.linalg.lstsq](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html).

Here you can find an example implementation:

http://glowingpython.blogspot.de/2012/03/linear-regression-with-numpy.html

Answer (score 1):

What you have written out, `b = y * X.T * np.linalg.inv(X * X.T)`, is the solution to the normal equations, which gives the least squares fit with a multi-linear model.  swang's response is correct (and EMS's elaboration)---you need to add a row of 1's to X. If you want some idea of why it works theoretically, keep in mind that you are finding `b_i` such that

```
y_j = sum_i b_i x_{ij}.
```

By adding a row of 1's, you are are setting `x_{(k+1)j} = 1` for all `j`, which means that you are finding b_i such that:

```
y_j = (sum_i b_i x_{ij}) + b_{k+1}
```

because the `k+1`st `x_ij` term is always equal to one.  Thus, `b_{k+1}` is your intercept term.